# Android - Facebook log in outside of an Activity with your own button

Tags: java, android, facebook, libgdx

EDIT: When I click my button and call `fbLogin()` The app automatically logs in but I still can't access my `onSuccess()` method and get it to print "success", is it beacuse I'm not doing it from my activities onCreate method, but how do I do that when Im using a button? (Im extending my Activity):

```
public class AndroidPlatform extends AndroidLauncher implements PlatformSpecific{

        private Activity context;
        private CallbackManager callbackManager;

        public AndroidPlatform(Activity context){
            this.context = context;
            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        }

        @Override
        public void fbLogin() {

        System.out.println("Hello Android");

            String a[] = new String[]{"user_friends"};
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(context, Arrays.asList(a)); //Log in to FB
            LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    System.out.println("Success");
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    System.out.println("Cancel");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error");
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }

    }
```

For clarity here is the class I extend (my activity):

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        initialize(new MyGdxGame(new AndroidPlatform(this)), config);
    }
}
```

If I can't access that method I cannot get any information on the user, The problem is I have to do it in this class, I can't do it in my activity, is there a way I can make that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To log in to facebook using your own button from a class that is not an Activity you can do the following:

The class you log in from:

```
    public AndroidPlatform(Activity context){
        this.context = context;
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void fbLogin() {

        String a[] = new String[]{"user_friends"};
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(context, Arrays.asList(a)); //Log in to FB
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                System.out.println("Success");
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(
                                    JSONObject object,
                                    GraphResponse response) {
                                // Application code
                                Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                            }
                        });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                System.out.println("Cancel");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
        });

    }

    public CallbackManager getCM(){
        return callbackManager;
    }
```

This is pretty standard, what is key is that you make a get-method for your `CallbackManager` in your class so you can call `onActivityResult` from your Activity like so:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        ap.getCM().onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

And that's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be overriding onActivityResult so that when Facebook returns control to your activity, the activity will be able to process the result using the callback manager that you registered.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.4#callback_handling for an example with the LoginButton.

Comment: Hi, I had tried that already and I realize the first edit of my question was pretty poor, please look again and see if you can find the problem.

Comment: Is onActivityResult called? The `onActivityResult` should be in the activity class, and you have to pass the result into your AndroidPlatform class

Comment: Hi, all the code I have is in the example, as you can see I call that method in my AndroidPlatform class

Comment: I recommend you post your answer and then accept it so that it will help anyone else who has the same problem :)